# How to overlay a fixed header while scrolling page content?

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie in coding, trying to setup a header on this page: http://s.agenziajaved.com/it/s/London/New-York-City.

As you can see in the image link provided below, the content comes in background of logo at top and I need to fix it by displaying just the white fill behind the logo. Your help will be appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgoCa.png

Comment: copy paste your css and html here / fiddle your efforts.

Comment: In the live site, it is white background..so wt u want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just add the property `background: white` to your `layout-header` class? That fixes your problem.